# How can I convert sha1 to hash

Tags: android

how can I convert this

11252411445171911438526

to be something like this!

c6ee47d1a8edbce28b1560b836abd388631983b6

anyone help ?

Comment: Just translate numbers you are having into hexadecimal system. If you need something else like convert some hash into some other hash type - say it explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

In case you want a SHA1 hash you can do something like this:

```
String input = "11252411445171911438526";
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
md.reset();
md.update(input.getBytes("utf8"));
String ouput = new BigInteger(1, md.digest()).toString(16);
```